# Does haste trump first strike, or vice versa?

Tags: adnd-1e, initiative

I've added a new enchantment to my AD&D game based on the "first strike" ability from *Magic: The Gathering*. It's simply defined as the ability to always go first in the round, every round.

If a character has a weapon with first strike, and the monster has a *haste* on and won initiative to go in the first attack segment of that round, who goes first and who second for that first attack in that round?

Answer (score 11):

Regardless of whether it's because of a tie on the initiative roll, magic, or something else, this is covered in the DMG on page 66, "Simultaneous Initiative". (It even mentions *haste* explicitly as falling under this rule.)

Basically, If they're both using weapons, then whoever has the weapon with the fastest speed factor goes first within the segment. Otherwise it's simultaneous and the attacks are both resolved before their effects are applied to the situation.

Since your "first strike" ability is a house rule, you can have it work any way you want, and just *say* that it goes first regardless of magic. But since you'll probably have to deal with "first strike" vs "first strike" at some point, I recommend using the existing guidelines on page 66 for this weapon ability. Sometimes that means that it *won't* go first, but then neither does the *MTG* ability "first strike" actually always go first.